# Using FB login on a website

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am working on a web based project that allows a user to login using a Facebook login. This part works as expected. However after logging in I want to display non-FB specific content specific to each user. How can I do this efficiently? For testing suppose I want to display a different greeting for each FB user and display a different background after successful login using FB username. Any sample code to play with would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what "Core" is.

Comment: what platform you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's pretty late to answer yet I would like to. I assume you want to differentiate between the greeting, for example, that gets generated for a core user (one signed up manually through form) and a user logged in using facebook, right? Well, you can store the facebook id of each user and then it would be easy for you to generate messages respectively!